# List of strings as CSV string in Json.Net

Tags: c#, json.net

I wonder if it is possible to serialize and deserialize any `List<string>` as a string of comma separated values in C# using Json.Net:

```
class MyDTO
{
    public int Age { get; set; } = 25;
    public string Name { get; set; } = "Jon";
    public List<string> Friends { get; set; } = new List<string> {"Jan", "Joe", "Tim"};
}

var serilalized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new MyDTO());

//serialized = { "name": "Jon", "age": 25, "friends": "Jan,Joe,Tim" }

var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyDTO>(serialized);

//deserialized.Name = "Jon", deserialized.Age = 25, deserialized.Friends = List<string> {"Jan", "Joe", "Tim"}
```

How could I achieve what the comments in the code reflect?

Implementing a custom `JsonConverter` is a good solution to this problem, but when I deserialize using the non generic version `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(serialized)`, the JsonConverter does not have effect and the deserialized value has type `JTokenType.String`, instead of `JTokenType.Array` that is the type that I want to get. For example:

```
JObject obj = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(serilalized);

JToken token = obj["friends"];

Console.WriteLine(token.Type == JTokenType.String); //prints true

Console.WriteLine(token.Type == JTokenType.Array); //prints false
```

I would like that the code above could print `false` in the first case and `true` in the second. Note that while deserializating I don't have the type `MyDTO` available.

Comment: `{age: 25, name: "Jon", friends = "\"Jan\", \"Joe\", \"Tim\""}` that's not valid json, so no.

Comment: I don't understand, you're asking how to generate invalid JSON?

Comment: What is wrong with `{age: 25, name: "Jon", friends: ["Jan", "Joe", "Tim"] }`? (in other words, did you try it and look at what it generated?)

Comment: sorry my point is not to generate invalid json, i am going to edit the question

Comment: The serialization does not work because `"[\"Jan\",\"Joe\",\"Tim\"]"` is a string not a json array. I added the last comment of the question trying to avoid this confusion.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I think that the comment reflect now what i want to accomplish.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25307714/customizing-json-net-serialization-turning-object-into-array-to-avoid-repetitio

Comment: You said *but when I deserialize using the non-generic version `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(serialized)`, the JsonConverter does not have effect*.  Can you provide code that shows the problem?  [It works fine for me](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Y33Puv).

Comment: @BrianRogers my case is when I am deserializing to a Json.Net JObject without the knowledge of the type of the .Net object

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure why you need this, but you can make a simple `JsonConverter` to do what you want:

```
public class ListToCsvConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(List<string>);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteValue(string.Join(",", (List<string>)value));
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        return new List<string>(((string)reader.Value).Split(','));
    }
}
```

Then add a `[JsonConverter]` attribute to the list property in your class that you want to be handled by the converter:

```
class MyDTO
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(ListToCsvConverter))]
    public List<string> Friends { get; set; } = new List<string> { "Jan", "Joe", "Tim" };
}
```

Of course, this solution assumes that none of your strings will have commas in them.  If your strings can contain commas, then you would need an escaping mechanism for the commas to ensure a successful round trip.  At that point I would recommend just sticking with the default serialization, since JSON already has such a mechanism.

Round-trip demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/dVh4Zq

---

If you don't have a DTO available to deserialize into, then you will have to work with a `JObject` and you won't be able to use the above converter.  Instead, you can use a helper method to convert the `JToken` containing the CSV string to a `JArray` after deserialization:

```
static JArray ConvertCsvToArray(JToken value)
{
    if (value.Type == JTokenType.String)
    {
        return JArray.FromObject(((string)value).Split(','));
    }
    throw new ArgumentException("The token does not contain a string value.");
}
```

Use it like this:

```
JObject obj = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(serialized);

JArray array = ConvertCsvToArray(obj["friends"]);
```

Comment: That was my solution, I thought a better one could be possible. Thank you very much @BrianRogers.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at `serilalized` in the debugger, it looks like this:

```
"{\"Age\":25,\"Name\":\"Jon\",\"Friends\":[\"Jan\",\"Joe\",\"Tim\"]}"
```

This is because `serilalized` is a string and that string has embedded `"` in it.

When printed to the console it looks like this:

```
{"Age":25,"Name":"Jon","Friends":["Jan","Joe","Tim"]}
```

Which is exactly correct (`Friends` is a list of `String`).

The only problem here is that you initialize `Friends` and the deserialization *adds* to that, resulting in 6 entries instead of 3.

If you feel you really need to have `Friends` serialize to a string of comma separated values (which I would not recommend), you would need to look at [JsonConverter](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm).

**Update:** Note that this does not work for deserializing to `JObject` (as you've now indicated that you want). You would need to look for strings with commas and `.Split` those for your destination object (assuming all strings with commas are supposed to be lists of string). **OR** just serialize like you had before and you get a `JArray` that has strings. This is exactly why I was not recommending you try and do this: non-standard representation of the data.

Comment: I see that you have not understood me. I am going to edit again.

Comment: Your code works fine as it is, and generates correct and usable JSON. If you *want* `Friends` as a comma separated list, then you need a lot more *non standard* code and I don't see any point for it if anything else working with the code will use normal JSON libraries.